# A weird issue on CSS selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and want to override the default `margin-bottom` when screen `min-width` is 768, for inline form groups belonging to a form identified by `#filter`. So I did:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #filter .form-inline .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, even when I added `important!` on the rule.

However, it does work after I removed the `#filter` in selector:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group {
    margin-bottom: 4px;
  }
}
```

That's really weird! I'm sure and tested that `#filter` can select the form. Can anyone tell me why?

The piece of code in Bootstrap I want to override is:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ...
}
```

But I only want to override this for the form `#filter`

The HTML code for the form is:

```
<form class="form-inline" id="filter" method="GET" action="<%= url("/blogs", false) %>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id" class="control-label">ID</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id" name="id" value="<%= params[:id] %>" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_id" class="control-label">UID</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="<%= params[:user_id] %>" />
  </div>

  ...

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Filter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the form?

Comment: Thanks. I've added the form code.

Comment: Try `#filter.form-inline .form-group` notice the lack of a space. `form-inline` is not a child of `#filter` but is a class of the same tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong selector `#filter .form-inline`. This means that `.form-inline` is the child of `#filter` which is incorrect.

What you need is `#filter.form-inline` which is a multi-selector. See [Multiple Class / ID and Class Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)

Comment: Thanks! My brain is exploding by 20+ commits in one day!